# How to sum identical rows in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I sum the identical values in a multidimensional array?
e.g If I have an array

```
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]],
   [[6,5,4],
    [4,7,2],
    [8,9,1]],
   [[2,8,9],
   [3,6,4],
   [8,2,5]]]
```

the result I want is (1+2+3)+(6+5+4)+(2+8+9)=40 and (4+5+6)+(4+7+2)+(3+6+4)=41 and (7+8+9)+(8+9+1)+(8+2+5)=57

Answer (score 0):

Given that your array `a`:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[6, 5, 4],
        [4, 7, 2],
        [8, 9, 1]],

       [[2, 8, 9],
        [3, 6, 4],
        [8, 2, 5]]])
```

You can use:

```
a.sum(axis = 2).sum(axis = 0)
```

results in:

```
array([40, 41, 57])
```

Comment: Specifically, I have a k-dimensional matrix `X[k,i,j]` where X={}, so how can I sum it according to the above example.

Comment: Use the exact same syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to go about it:

```
numbers = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
           [[6,5,4], [4,7,2], [8,9,1]],
           [[2,8,9], [3,6,4], [8,2,5]]]

sum1 = sum2 = sum3 = 0

for element in numbers :
    sum1 += sum (element [0])
    sum2 += sum (element [1])
    sum3 += sum (element [2])

print (sum1, sum2, sum3)
```

Comment: Specifically, I have a k-dimensional matrix X[k,i,j] where X={}, so how can I sum it according to the above example